why did my color of JPanel fill up all the window gui? I didn't know if there's something wrong in the code or the compiler?
the window appeared like this:

this is my code:
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class gui2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel bluepanel = new JPanel();
        bluepanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        bluepanel.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);
        
        JPanel greenpanel = new JPanel();
        greenpanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        greenpanel.setBounds(250, 0, 250, 250);
        
        JPanel redpanel = new JPanel();
        redpanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redpanel.setBounds(0, 250, 250, 250);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("what?");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(bluepanel);
        frame.add(greenpanel);
        frame.add(redpanel);
    }

}


I had tried to add new JPanel or even setBackground Color, but it cannot solve the problem.

It's not clear (to me) what your problem is. Does the image show the result you got and that is not the result that you want?

Read the Swing tutorial on Layout Managers for the proper solution.

"why did my color of JPanel fill up all the window"-> because the default LayoutManager of JFrame is BorderLayout and, if no constraint is used when adding a component, CENTER is used, which fills the whole available region (javadoc) -- maybe you want to use a GridLayout instead

You should set JFrame layout to null.
Here is updated code.
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class gui2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create panels
        JPanel bluepanel = new JPanel();
        bluepanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        bluepanel.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);
        
        JPanel greenpanel = new JPanel();
        greenpanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        greenpanel.setBounds(250, 0, 250, 250);
        
        JPanel redpanel = new JPanel();
        redpanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redpanel.setBounds(0, 250, 250, 250);
        
        // Create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("what?");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null); // Set layout manager to null
        frame.add(bluepanel);
        frame.add(greenpanel);
        frame.add(redpanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
} 


(1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Swing is already deprecated. I just provided code for him to understand.

@драган-јованковић you wrote (in your comment): Swing is already deprecated.  Please provide proof which confirms your claim.

@Abra It's not officialy deprecated, but since there is javaFx which is a massive improvement, then compared to javaFx, it is indeed deprecated.
